# How can I make int and for have a different color

Tags: intellij-idea

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHwpE.png)

I am trying to change my colors in IntelliJIdea, in particular I am trying to get something more similar to VSCode or Eclipse. But I cannot find a way to change my types to a different color than other keywords - for example, I would like `int` to be green, while `for` is orange. Is there some way to do that? Or do I need to use `Integer` instead of `int` from now on?

I tried following https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2013/06/textmate-bundles-in-pycharm/, but this did not work for me.

Comment: See [how to configure colours](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html) in the IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I know how to change colors, but those things seem to be in the same category, and the guide does not tell how to change the categories.

Comment: It does. Just scroll down a bit. You can change the existing themes, or even define your custom one as you wish.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Can you check again? I know I can change the color of a specific category, but `int` and `for` are in the same category. I can not find the instructions how to work around it in the article you sent.